# Extracting area in orthophoto high resolution image tab file?

Tags: mapinfo, tab, files

How can I extract an area in an orthophoto high resolution image tab file?

I tried to translate it in MapInfo to other data files but cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Set your mapper window width and height to cover just the required area.

Then do File > Save Window As...

Tick 'Create a Geographically Referenced Tab File'.

Choose your desired pixel dimensions. It will help to know the GSD of the original orthophoto. Using that and the 'ground distance' that your window covers will help you save the new image with the same level of detail.